# Batch file - restart program every day at fix time

Tags: batch-file

In windows environment ,

I have to restart some program forcefully .

1  > How to create batch or exe file for this.

2 > should I run particular batch  in task scheduler .

HELP NEEDED**

Comment: You can do it all with Task Scheduler. Create a Daily Trigger.  Then tell it to Stop the task if it runs longer than 1 day. You might have to play with the options on the settings tab as well.

Answer (score 1):

A batch file that springs to life once a day.

```
:Loop
rem 86400 secs is 24 hours
timeout /t 86400
Taskkill /f /Im notepad.exe
start "" notepad
Goto Loop
```

A VBS file to start a hidden batch file.

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run """c:\windows\system32\Mybat.bat""", 0, false
```

Comment: Technically this doesn't spring to life once per day, it runs constantly and also needs invoking per session. The question title asks for a fixed time, _this only provides a fixed duration_, and asks about task scheduler which you've omited from your answer.

Comment: Well it does spring to life once a day, what do you think timeout does.

Comment: ACatInLove, it starts a countdown in approximate seconds from `86400` until it reaches `0`. When `0` is reached the next line `TaskKill …` is run. _(that countdown is always running between succesive `TaskKill`'s)_!